# how to make my query select variables faster

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, time

i have sql querys which must be work fast

querys are working but they are  slow how can i make them work faster

this is the my first query which is very slow for what i trying to do

```
select 
distinct symbol as s
,(select count(distinct login) from orders where symbol = s and cmd < 2)as users
,(select count(cmd) from orders where symbol=s and cmd=1) as sat
,(select count(cmd) from orders where symbol=s and cmd=0) as al
,(select ifnull(sum(volume),0) from orders where symbol=s and cmd=0) as al_lot
,(select ifnull(sum(volume),0) from orders where symbol=s and cmd=1) as sat_lot
,(select count(distinct login) from orders where symbol=s and cmd=0) as a
,(select count(distinct login) from orders dd where symbol=s and (select sum(volume) from orders where symbol=dd.symbol and orders.login=dd.login and cmd = 0) < (select sum(volume) from orders where symbol=dd.symbol and dd.login=orders.login and cmd=1)) as b
from orders where symbol in("EURUSD","XAUUSD","GAUTRY","GBPUSD","USDJPY","USDTRY","BRENT","CRUDE","DAX30","DM#","ES#","BTCUSD") group by s,cmd;
```

this is the query that i am currently using (i tried to make it faster my first query)

```
Select 
src.symbol as Symbol
,IFNULL(count(distinct deals.LOGIN),0) as Users
,IFNULL(count(mybuy.LOGIN),0) as BuyDeals
,IFNULL(count(mysell.LOGIN),0) as SellDeals
,IFNULL(sum(mybuy.volume),0) as BuyVolume
,IFNULL(sum(mysell.volume),0) as SellVolume
,(select count(distinct login) from orders where symbol=deals.symbol and cmd =0) as a
,(select count(distinct login) from orders dd where symbol=src.symbol and (select sum(volume) from orders where symbol=dd.symbol and login=dd.login and cmd = 0) < (select sum(volume) from orders where symbol=dd.symbol and dd.login=login and cmd=1)) as b

from
(Select * from orders Where cmd<2)src
LEFT OUTER JOIN(Select `order`, symbol, login, volume from orders where cmd<2 group by `order`,symbol,login)deals on deals.`order`=src.`order` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN(Select `order`, symbol, login, volume from orders where cmd=0 group by `order`,symbol,login)mybuy on mybuy.`order`=src.`order`
LEFT OUTER JOIN(Select `order`, symbol, login, volume from orders where cmd=1 group by `order`,symbol,login)mysell on mysell.`order`=src.`order`

where src.symbol in ('EURUSD','XAUUSD','GAUTRY','GBPUSD','USDJPY','USDTRY','BRENT','CRUDE','DAX30','DM#','ES#','BTCUSD') group by src.symbol order by symbol;
```

but it is still too slow it must work way more faster

and this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `login` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `symbol` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `digits` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmd` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open__time` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open_price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `sl` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `tp` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_time` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gw_volume` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiration` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conv_reserv` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conv_rate1` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `conv_rate2` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `commission` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `commission_agent` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `storage` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `profit` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `taxes` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `magic` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gw_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activation` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gw_open_price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gw_close_price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `margin_rate` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: You must remove all subqueries.

Comment: but i need the values they are giving me @Akina

Comment: You must convert them to JOIN form.

Comment: and the second one i remove some of them but i dont have any idea to how to remove and get variables at my second querys subqueries @Akina

Comment: i tried to get data by using LEFT OUTER JOIN so i didn't need to use subquery @Akina

Comment: `symbol` is not a stock ticker symbol?  If it is, then why no decimal places on `price`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation!

```
select symbol,
       count(distinct case when cmd < 2 then login) as users,
       sum(cmd = 1) as sat,
       sum(cmd = 0) as al,
       sum(case when cmd = 0 then volume else 0 end) as al_lot,
       sum(case when cmd = 1 then volume else 0 end) as sat_lot,
       count(distinct case when cmd = 0 then login) as a
from orders
where symbol in ('EURUSD', 'XAUUSD', 'GAUTRY', 'GBPUSD', 'USDJPY', 'USDTRY',
                 'BRENT', 'CRUDE', 'DAX30', 'DM#', 'ES#', 'BTCUSD'
                )
group by symbol;
```

This does not include the last column which references `dd`.  I don't see a definition for `dd` anywhere, so that looks like it would cause an error.  In any case, you should be able to structure that logic using an expression with aggregation functions as well.